# Is there a reason the Kernels from the Kernel PPA don't have various features turned on?

Tags: kernel

I tried to use a Kernel PPA version of 3.16 today to debug an issue I've been having. Everything was working well until I noticed that my usual AuFS mounts weren't online. I combine a few directories because I don't have enough space on one drive.

Long story sort, I found they had been removed from the Kernel. OverlayFS too. It left me scuppered. I'm back on 3.13 now and I know full well how to recompile a kernel, **I'm just wondering if there's a technical reason *why*** both AuFS and OverlayFS have been explicitly turned off.

You can actually see in the [config patch](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.16-utopic/0003-configs-based-on-Ubuntu-3.16.0-7.12.patch) where they've been turned off:

```
-CONFIG_AUFS_BDEV_LOOP=y
-# CONFIG_AUFS_BRANCH_MAX_1023 is not set
-CONFIG_AUFS_BRANCH_MAX_127=y
-# CONFIG_AUFS_BRANCH_MAX_32767 is not set
-# CONFIG_AUFS_BRANCH_MAX_511 is not set
-# CONFIG_AUFS_BR_FUSE is not set
-# CONFIG_AUFS_BR_HFSPLUS is not set
-# CONFIG_AUFS_BR_RAMFS is not set
-# CONFIG_AUFS_DEBUG is not set
-CONFIG_AUFS_EXPORT=y
-CONFIG_AUFS_FS=m
-# CONFIG_AUFS_HNOTIFY is not set
-CONFIG_AUFS_INO_T_64=y
-# CONFIG_AUFS_RDU is not set
-CONFIG_AUFS_SBILIST=y
-# CONFIG_AUFS_SHWH is not set
...
-CONFIG_OVERLAYFS_FS=m
```

Comment: That's something you would need to ask directly to the people in charge of the packaged kernels. Also remember they are not recomended for daily use.

Comment: I would of thought something could be found in [CHANGES](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.16-utopic/CHANGES).... asking the developers etc is probably the easiest way to go though. there is also some stuff about aufs in the other patches

Comment: N.B. which builds of 3.16 don't work?

Comment: Was looking for ``overlayfs`` on ``3.15`` and hit the same issue. Removing both ``aufs`` and ``overlayfs`` seems ill minded...

Answer (score 1):

The kernels Ubuntu provides in the mainline PPA are *unmodified* versions of the Linux kernels found on [kernel.org](http://kernel.org/). They do not add any extra/additional patches when building them when compared to the officially supported Ubuntu kernel builds.

AuFS and OverlayFS are not part of the upstream kernel and thus are omitted when Ubuntu builds these mainline kernels.